# Revoke own edit

Tags: feature-request, edits

I have made an edit but soon after realized that I was mistaken. As my edits aren't automatically approved, yet, it is now pending in peer review.

I want to revoke my own edit, is that possible?

Comment: Where is it? I'll decline it for you.  No, there's no way to revoke it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150922/is-this-sfinae-technique-involving-variadic-templates-valid, seems like somebody else did it just now

Comment: Looks like it was already declined.